# Can I serialize/deserialize JSON from protocol buffers with C++?

Tags: c++, json, protocol-buffers

There are frameworks for Java and other languages that help connect protocol buffers to JSON, but I have not seen a native solution in C++.

Is there a library/framework that I can use to connect C++ protocol buffer objects to JSON?

Comment: Not really an answer, but this will depend hugely on the tools of each. It is trivial with protobuf-net, since that is designed to work with POCO/DTO objects, which most .NET JSON serializers will happily work with. But without that you might need to map it to a JSON-friendly DTO model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm developing one. I'm using the protobuf's reflection mechanism to parse any generated protobuf. Here http://corbasim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/protobuf2json_exported.zip you can find an initial implementation of this idea. It currently just parse string fields, but I want to support any type as soon as possible.

For a message Foo:

```
message Foo {
   optional string text = 1;
}
```

it can parse instances of Foo by this way:

```
Foo foo;

const std::string json_foo = "{\"text\": \"Hello world\"}";

protobuf2json::json::parse(foo, json_foo)
```

By the same way, I want to write a JSON serializer from protobuf generated types.

There is a similar question here:

[C++ Protobuf to/from JSON conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007876/c-protobuf-to-from-json-conversion/7663847#7663847)

Answer (score 1):

[pb2json](https://github.com/renenglish/pb2json) is another library that can be used.

Comment: thanks, this is going to be useful in some other piece of work :)