# C++ Protobuf to/from JSON conversion

Tags: c++, json, serialization, protocol-buffers

Is anyone familiar with a stable C++ solution (library, code snippet etc.) which converts protobuf messages to/from JSON?

Comment: protobuf messages *by themselves* don't really have enough info for that; I would just deserialize into an object model (protobuf), and the serialize (your choice of json engine) that... I don't use C++ though, so I don't know the exact options available there (it is a breeze with protobuf-net, but : different platform)

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, Marc. It would definitely save a lot of time. I'm also considering to try protobuf's reflection mechanism. Hopefully one of the approaches will work :)

Comment: I think that using protobuf's reflection mechanism is a good approach to make a generic JSON serializer/parser from JSON to protobuf generated types. I've made something like this, but to CORBA IDL generated types in http://code.google.com/p/corbasim/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2544580/545127

Comment: protobuf v3 supports JSON, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291335/757777

Comment: I think this thread does not deserve to be closed, as it could be precious as information.

Answer (score 8):

This one is better IMO: https://github.com/shramov/json2pb

it does conversion in both directions and handles extensions

Answer (score 5):

[pbjson](https://github.com/yinqiwen/pbjson) is another one, which built on rapidjson, maybe faster.

Comment: This one did the trick for me.  I tried `json2pb`first and had throuble getting it to work (and found little in the way of documentation).  I didn't have much trouble getting this `pbjson` tool working with their test example, and I found that it took only a minor effort to edit their test driver to parse my data.

Comment: By the way, for what it's worth, the author of this `pbjson` tool says they drew inspiration from `pb2json`.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a bootstrap implementation of a JSON parser for protobuf generated types, using the its reflection mechanism, and adapting the parse I've made previously for CORBA IDL generated types.

You can find it at http://corbasim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/protobuf2json_exported.zip

By this way for each protobuf defined message, you will be able to parse its instances by doing:

```
Foo foo;

const std::string json_foo = "{\"text\": \"Hello world\"}";

protobuf2json::json::parse(foo, json_foo);
```

It's just an initial implementation, and it just support string fields, but it's easy to implement all kind of fields.

Answer (score 2):

[pb2json](https://github.com/renenglish/pb2json) is another C++ library that can do this.