# Protocol buffer3 and json

Tags: c++, json, protocol-buffers, proto3

Protocol buffer v3 claims, that library is json friendly (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), but I cannot find how to achieve get that mapping. Should I add some plugin, or some option into protoc, or call something special instead SerializeTo/ParseFrom?

Is it someone who use that feature?

Answer (score 33):

I'm using Protobuf 3.3.0, which does have a built-in JSON serializer and parser. You can use 2 functions from `google/protobuf/util/json_util.h` called `MessageToJsonString()` and `JsonStringToMessage()` to make your C++ generated `Message` objects go to and from JSON respectively.

Here's a simple test that uses them:
`test-protobuf.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
}
```

`test-protobuf.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <google/protobuf/util/json_util.h>

#include "test-protobuf.pb.h"

int main()
{
  std::string json_string;
  SearchRequest sr, sr2;

  // Populate sr.
  sr.set_query(std::string("Hello!"));
  sr.set_page_number(1);
  sr.set_result_per_page(10);

  // Create a json_string from sr.
  google::protobuf::util::JsonPrintOptions options;
  options.add_whitespace = true;
  options.always_print_primitive_fields = true;
  options.preserve_proto_field_names = true;
  MessageToJsonString(sr, &json_string, options);

  // Print json_string.
  std::cout << json_string << std::endl;


  // Parse the json_string into sr2.
  google::protobuf::util::JsonParseOptions options2;
  JsonStringToMessage(json_string, &sr2, options2);

  // Print the values of sr2.
  std::cout
    << sr2.query() << ", "
    << sr2.page_number() << ", "
    << sr2.result_per_page() << std::endl
  ;

  return 0;
}
```

You can compile these files (assuming that you have protobuf, a compiler, and CMake installed) by using the following `CMakeLists.txt` file (tested on Windows).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(test-protobuf)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

# Use static runtime for MSVC
if(MSVC)
  foreach(flag_var
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
    if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
      string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
  endforeach(flag_var)
endif(MSVC)

protobuf_generate_cpp(test-protobuf-sources test-protobuf-headers
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test-protobuf.proto"
)

list(APPEND test-protobuf-sources
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test-protobuf.cpp"
)

add_executable(test-protobuf ${test-protobuf-sources} ${test-protobuf-headers})
target_include_directories(test-protobuf
  PUBLIC
    ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
target_link_libraries(test-protobuf
  ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Assuming that `CMakeLists.txt`, `test-protobuf.proto`, and `test-protobuf.cpp` are in the same directory, here are the commands to compile and run them on Windows with Visual Studio 15 2017 and 64-bit protobuf libraries.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
cmake --build . --config Release
Release/test-protobuf
```

You should see the following output:

```
{
 "query": "Hello!",
 "page_number": 1,
 "result_per_page": 10
}

Hello!, 1, 10
```

Comment: Any chance JSON conversion support can be done in protobuf-C ?

Comment: Really nice, any way to have the a hex representation of bytes values instead of what seems to be base64?

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf has json api for C#. There are some json class for C# in [google protobuf reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter) and You can find some tests in [github protobuf repository](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/test/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormatTest.java) for java and c++.

Comment: I'm building up experience with Protobuf and C#. The JsonFormatter only accepts IMessage as input. Suppose you only have some instance of a Protobuf message...How to convert it to IMessage so it can be serialized to Json?

Comment: Here is the answer from Protobuf -> JSON: string jsonMessage = Google.Protobuf.JsonFormatter.Default.Format((IMessage)person); .............An From JSON -> Protobuf:  IMessage message = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person)); Person personFromJSON = (Person)Google.Protobuf.JsonParser.Default.Parse(jsonMessage, message.Descriptor);